# Have a list of ID's I need to run through and use slicing to replace certain characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of Identifiers that are 8 digits each, and 6 dicts I need to loop through and replace slices in these IDs with different letters and numbers.

I managed to get the first one correctly but the next step in the loop is giving me issues.  Here's my code:

```
for I in ID:

    if I[:3] in mapA_dict:
        for inp in mapA_dict:
            I = I.replace(inp, mapA_dict[inp])
    print I
    if len(I) <= 8:
            for I[0] in mapA2_dict:
                for inp in mapA2_dict:
                    I = I.replace(inp, mapA2_dict[inp])
                print I
```

I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-49924532d1ff> in <module>()
     11 #         print I
     12     if len(I) <= 8:
---> 13             for I[0] in mapA2_dict:
     14                 for inp in mapA2_dict:
     15                     I = I.replace(inp, mapA2_dict[inp])

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Do you mean `for` on the line with the error, or `if`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site. Members, such as yourself, ask questions while other members attempt to answer their questions. For more information about asking questions and receiving excellent responses, see [ask] (and, more specifically, [mcve]). I note that your post is missing the essential element of a good question: *the question itself!*. Do you have a specific question to ask?

Comment: Yes, sorry.  That semi worked, except now I'm getting duplicate printed ID's before the change and after the change

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because strings do not support item assignments.

If you want to iterate over `I` and alter it character by character you'll need to create a new string as you pass over it, sort of like

```
if len(I) <= 8:
    new_I = ''
    for i in I:
        if i in mapA2_dict:
            new_I.append(mapA2_dict[i])
        else:
            new_I.append(i)
```

A cleaner approach though, based on what it looks like you're doing, is to use a [translation table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans).

That would turn that code into something along the lines of

```
import string
mapA2 = string.maketrans(from="abc", to="def")
# This equates to translating `a` to `d`, `b` to `e`, `c` to `f`
if len(I) <= 8:
    I = I.translate(mapA2)
```